# Keycloak SPIs jar file doesn't get deployed

Tags: jboss, keycloak

When I deploy my jar, my SPIs within it, do not get added. I can’t find them on the Server Info page on Keycloak’s dashboard, or anywhere else.

Except, I do see my jar added to the `themeResources` section of Server Info.

Due to this, I assumed there’s an issue with the Java SPIs I try to deploy within the same jar. I suspect my `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` isn’t correct. I have bunch of maven dependencies that I use in my SPIs but I didn’t define those in the JBoss XML file.

Should all dependencies be defined there, or I should just keep the org.keycloak and org.jboss?

My jboss-deployment-structure.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-core"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-services"/>
            <module name="org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core-public"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.logging"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

If this isn't an issue, what could possibly be?

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing same issue. You need to export="true" with module name as follows

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31237468)